# How to configure postgresql-9.2 to know blk_write_time in pg_stat_database

Tags: postgresql-9.2, statistics

Interested in the procedure for collecting block write statistics of PostgreSQL 9.2.

Steps followed for configuration, could get blk_read time but not blk_write_time

1. `CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;` and `CREATE EXTENSION dblink;`
2. Changed postgresql.conf file

   ```
   # - Query/Index Statistics Collector -

   track_activities = on
   track_counts = on
   track_io_timing = on
   track_functions = all           # none, pl, all
   track_activity_query_size = 1024    # (change requires restart)
   update_process_title = on
   stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'

   # - Background Writer -

   bgwriter_delay = 200ms          # 10-10000ms between rounds
   bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100     # 0-1000 max buffers written/round
   bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2.0       # 0-10.0 multipler on buffers scanned/round
   ```
3. Restarted Postgres Server
4. Performed around 2000 inserts to table
5. But could not view the blk_write_time.

Answer (score 1):

configuration above is correct. Before viewing the blk_write_time, do a vacuum. If you still see a 0 try increasing the inserts from 2000 to say 1000000.

Step 5: 
vacuum;
Step 6:
select datname, blk_write_time from pg_stat_database;